# In Moodle How do I allow a single student a second attempt on a quiz?

Tags: moodle

I am working in the moodle right now How do I allow a single student/Candidate/individual user a second attempt on a quiz?

Is there any possible way to do that because if I allow a quiz retake it may apply on a group level and every user can attempt quiz.

Comment: This seems like a support question for whoever runs Moodle, or are you programming the quiz yourself? (In which case, we will need to see the code before we're able to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a support question rather than a developer question.

But you can find the answer in the documentation.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Quiz_FAQ#Attempts

Go to the quiz admin menu and select "User overrides"

Then select a user and change the number of attempts.